# CPLEX OPL IP-gap in main block and execute in the model

Tags: cplex, opl

In my model I want to set up an IP gap. I did this in a main block:

```
main {

    thisOplModel.generate();


    cplex.epgap = 0.005; 

    if (cplex.solve()) {

        var obj = cplex.getObjValue();
        writeln("Objective function value: " + obj);
    }

}
```

In the model itself I have a couple of execute blocks for console output and excel writing.
e.g.:

```
execute{
  writeln("MECHANICAL HARVESTING");
 for(var j in J){

   write("j= "+j + " ");

   for(var t in T){
     var x_out = 0;

     for(var k in K){
       for(var b in B){
         if(k == 1){x_out = x_out + x[j][t][k][b];}
       }
     }


     write(x_out + " ");
   }
   writeln("");


 }
 writeln(""); 
}
```

When I run the model I get a solution, however the execute blocks are not performed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call postProcess.

For instance in your code you should change

```
main {

    thisOplModel.generate();


    cplex.epgap = 0.005; 

    if (cplex.solve()) {

        var obj = cplex.getObjValue();
        writeln("Objective function value: " + obj);
    }

}
```

into

```
main {

    thisOplModel.generate();


    cplex.epgap = 0.005; 

    if (cplex.solve()) {

        var obj = cplex.getObjValue();
        writeln("Objective function value: " + obj);
        thisOplModel.postProcess(); // call postProcess
    }

}
```